# How to create a variable inside a variable's name?

Tags: c

i want this loop to add values to 5 different variables named coefficient1-5,
i know how to do it with an array but i want the vars to be regular integers.

```
for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
    coefficient(i) = Dice();
}
```

How do i do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compute variable names at runtime in C - so that can't be done. You need an array, though you can use an array of pointers if the variables themselves are not in an array.

```
int coefficient1;
int coefficient2;
int coefficient3;
int coefficient4;
int coefficient5;

int *ptrs[] = { 
  &coefficient1,
  &coefficient2,
  &coefficient3,
  &coefficient4,
  &coefficient5,
};
for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
    *ptrs[i] = Dice();
}
```

But if this is a real case, just unroll the small loop yourself

```
coefficient1 = Dice();
coefficient2 = Dice();
coefficient3 = Dice();
coefficient4 = Dice();
coefficient5 = Dice();
```

Answer (score 1):

Succinctly, you don't.

The only mechanism that might approach achieving it is dynamic loading. On systems using `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`, if the variables are external, you might be able to look them up with `dlsym()` on an appropriate handle, but this is a sledgehammer to crack a nut — and a nut that doesn't need cracking in the first place.  Note that this would not work for local variables (whether automatic or static), and might not work for static variables at file scope.

---

#### Hare-brained Techniques

```
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
    case 0: coefficient1 = Dice(); break;
    case 1: coefficient2 = Dice(); break;
    case 2: coefficient3 = Dice(); break;
    case 3: coefficient4 = Dice(); break;
    case 4: coefficient5 = Dice(); break;
    }
}
```

Note that it would be better, though, to write:

```
coefficient1 = Dice();
coefficient2 = Dice();
coefficient3 = Dice();
coefficient4 = Dice();
coefficient5 = Dice();
```

This one is the non-hare-brained scheme while you can't use an array for the coefficients; forego the loop because you don't have an array to use.

This uses a loop and an adjunct data structure (an array of pointers).  It isn't a good idea.

```
int *coeffs[] = { &coefficient1, &coefficient2, &coefficient3, &coefficient4, &coefficient5 };
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    *coeffs[i] = Dice();
```